# How to select specific type of child which has other types of siblings in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to add background color to only group 3

```css
.group {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent .group:nth-child(3) {
  background: red;
  /*not working*/
}

.parent .group:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: red;
  /*not working*/
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="group">Group 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="group">Group 2</li>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="group">Group 3</li>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="group">Group 4</li>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="group">Group 5</li>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="group">Group 6</li>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

nth-child doesn't work because it still refers to the nth-child of the parent. So `.parent .group:nth-child(3)` would refer to "item 2" because its the third child of `.parent`. Your best bet would properly be to add a specific class to the element you want to style.

Comment: It is 3rd party HTML can't change, had to manage using CSS

Answer (score 0):

I found this way is working fine.

Instead of targeting the `3rd` child, use the `9th` child. I don't have the best explanation of what is going on but I think the [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) is referring to the `li` in `ul`.

```css
.group {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent .group:nth-child(3) {
  background: red;
  /*not working*/
}

.parent .group:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: red;
  /*not working*/
}

.parent .group:nth-child(9) {
  background: red;
  /*working*/
}
```

```html
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="group">Group 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="group">Group 2</li>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="group">Group 3</li>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="group">Group 4</li>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="group">Group 5</li>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="group">Group 6</li>
  <li class="item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="item">Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `item`s are dynamic and if no. of items changed then styles will apply to wrong element